# Error in MySQL query for references one column to another table

Tags: mysql, sql, create-table

I have the MySQL query as below -

```
CREATE TABLE city
{
    city_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    city_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    state_id int(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (city_id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(state_id) REFERENCES state(state_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE 
}
```

what may be the possible error as I am not table to create the table `'city'`

Structure of the table is very simple

first table named state

```
state_id | state_name
```

another table named city

```
city_id city_name state_id
```

As database table can be easily seen I want to keep refrence to the **table city** `state_id` to the **table state** `state_id`

I am still very beginner but I think code I written should work but it not? Why? Any suggestion?

Comment: Why are you using curly brackets? Apart from that, assuming you have a table called state, everything should work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are using clurly braces `{}` instead of round brackets `()`

```
CREATE TABLE city
(
     city_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
     city_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     state_id int(50) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (city_id), 
     FOREIGN KEY(state_id) REFERENCES state(state_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE 
)
```

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: @hd1 you ans is also same but this user has presented better way to so to award someone i choose him and don't forgot i gave +1 for u as well

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong braces...

```
CREATE TABLE city ( city_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, city_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, state_id int(50) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (city_id), FOREIGN KEY(state_id) REFERENCES state(state_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see you are missing the basic of the mysql don't use `{}` in the sql query and in here replace that with `()` as suggested above the answere

have some reference about the **PRIMARY KEY** [go to this link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp)  and also documentation kindly go to [MYSQL PRIMARY KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-primary-keys.html)

you can have some basic of **FOREIGN KEY** or the references visit [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) and also documentation kindly go to [MYSQL FOREIGN KEY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-foreign-keys.html)